# Deleting subfolder and files in window through cmd and timestamp backup

Tags: cmd, timestamp

I want to delete files and folders from a folder by using cmd in windows.How can i do?

And i need to copy a file and paste appending timestamp by time.

Help will be appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To delete all files and subfolders in directory, You can use powershell:

`powershell -Command "Remove-Item 'path\to\directory' -Recurse -Force"`

- `path\to\directory` is the place from where You would like to delete those files.

Or:

```
del /q "path\to\directory\*"
FOR /D %%p IN ("path\to\directory\*.*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q
```

Comment: without power shell using cmd how can i

Comment: I have edited the answer.